# Should I add assert validation on boolean doctrine field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine entity that has boolean field. Should I add Symfony validation for it (for type boolean), or my form is correctly validated by inferring the type automatically?

```
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\.... <- do I have to apply any Symfony assertion here?
     */
    private $isActive;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have only two cases. Value is present or not - so true or false.
I imagine a validator only in one case if this checkbox has to be set by user always like "accept disclaimer" during registration process

Comment: I am doing spreadsheet import. User can enter anything in spreadsheet, but there are only 2 valid values for this. What then?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Lazy Ants has said, you would only need to assert the type as bool if this field is nullable. -- That's because `null` and `false` are not identical.

You would only need this scenario if not all of the entity is going to be populated immediately though, for example a multi step form you're going to persist across each step hop or have auto-save capability for. If the entire entity is being populated in a single request the property should not be nullable.

Comment: trying to implement validation on an excel file import here. It would make sense to me to make it nullable in case the user enters "yes" or "no" incorrectly in the cell. - then i could assert boolean type and get an error for that situation. However when i try that, i get a 500 because of the boolean type in the database column.... Thoughts anyone?

Comment: @Sharkfin that's a completely separate scenario. You should post that as a new question. :)